# Using an MS-DOS batch file to run a Win32 application

Tags: win32

If I write a batch file that involves executing a Windows program, will the batch file pause until the opened program is closed, or will I have to use "PAUSE" to, well, pause the batch file until I've finished with the program?

Comment: The batch file will not pause, after the WIn32 program is executed, the script will just end.

Comment: If you want the batch file to suspend, precede the invocation with `start /wait ` (on the same line).

Comment: I just tried it in Windows 7, and when the Win32 app was run, the batch file froze and resumed when I quit the app. Does it behave differently in Win10?

Comment: AFH, it worked without the "start /wait".